# symfony 2 json request from titanium xhr

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony, titanium

I have an xhr post request from titanium client to symfony2 server. did this a lot of times, but this one, can't get any the post parameter that I need to be processed in the code.

my construct method (or a chunk of it) is as follow

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
}
```

so, at anytime in my controller's actions when I `var_dump` `$this->request->request->getContent();`
 I get as output

```
string(43) "id=9&token=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
```

but I don't know why when I try to access `$this->request->get('token')` I got null

these are request parameters after the initialization

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#83 (1) {
["parameters":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
}
```

and the request header parameter bag

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#79 (2) {
["headers":protected]=>
array(12) {
["connection"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "close"
}
["cache-control"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "max-age=43200"
}
["host"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "free.domain.com"
}
["user-agent"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(59) "Appcelerator Titanium/3.5.0 (iPhone/7.1; iPhone OS; it_IT;)"
}
["cookie"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "PHPSESSID=saohjtso3767nohqfe0knd8ca6"
}
["accept-encoding"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "gzip, deflate"
}
["accept-language"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "it-it"
}
["content-length"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "43"
}
["content-type"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(48) "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
}
["accept"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
}
["x-requested-with"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "XMLHttpRequest"
}
["x-titanium-id"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "e46d43b1-9136-41b2-93da-6b1d5b3c4580"
}
}
["cacheControl":protected]=>
array(1) {
["max-age"]=>
string(5) "43200"
}
}
```

ps.
titanium side I send my json request as follow

```
xhr.open("POST", url,true);
xhr.send(data);
```

but when I go

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

server side, I can access the `$this->request->get('token')` without any problem

my problem is that I want (always did) to send data not as `JSON.stringify(data)` because I want also to send blob files (images).

pps.
just in case, if I didn't need to send images from mobile, I could arrange my server script this way:

```
$data = json_decode($this->request->getContent(), true);
    $this->request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
```

but doesn't work with files.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the fact that the image sent by titanium client xhr wouldn't work. infact leaving

```
$data = json_decode($this->request->getContent(), true);
    $this->request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
```

symfony2 side, would let me get the `$this->request->file('image')`  but I don't have to `JSON.stringify(data)` when I'm sending titanium side. hope this helps to somebody